# Add parent to url (PHP)

Tags: php, url

So my boss asked me to modify some urls of our page like so:

What we have -> [www.domain.com/finaPage](http://www.domain.com/finaPage)

What he wants -> [www.domain.com/parent/finalPage](http://www.domain.com/parent/finalPage)

I tried creating a directory named 'parent' and accesing the pages from there and it worked fine. The problem is that we alredy have a page named 'parent' that broke when I created the folder with the same name on the same directory.

So I can either have the urls ok and the parent page broken... or I can have the parent page ok but the urls wrong.

Somebody knows how can I fix this?

Web is fully made with PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your can move your `parent` web page to a newly created parent folder and rename it to index.php

```
parent/index.php
```

so, when someone visit [www.domain.com/parent](http://www.domain.com/parent) it will show the renamed index.php file

and just put your `finalpage`  in parent folder

```
parent/finalpage.php
```

So, when someone visit [www.domain.com//finalPage](http://www.domain.com//finalPage) it will show above page

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with .htaccess, however, you ask for a PHP example.

```
<?php
  if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/parent' ) {
    // load the parent page
  } elseif( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/parent/finaPage' ){
    // load the finaPage
  } else {
    // 404 or whatever you want to do
  }

?>
```

Comment: Can you share the .htaccess solution please?